# Give rank based on two variables of data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with var1, var2 variables. Based on var2(highest to lowest) I have to assign a rank if there are identical values for var2 we have to consider corresponding values of var1(highest to lowest) to give rank and the rank should be in sorted. can any one suggest how I can do in R.

```
var1   var2   rank
 234   1456      1
  24    456      3 
  34    456      2
  68    343      4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `frank` from `library(data.table)`.  With `frank` you specify descending order using a `-` in front of the variable name.

```
frank(dt, -var2, -var1)
```

The data:

```
dt = fread("var1, var2, rank
    234, 1456, 1
    24, 456 , 3
    34, 456 , 2
    68, 343 , 4")
```

Comment: in case var2 has same values for two rows, I have to consider var1(highest value one top rank) for only those two rows to give rank

Comment: that is what this does - the second variable is a tie-breaker

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it is by ordering it by the two variables and assign a sequence from 1 to the row index to the rank column

```
    df <- data.frame(var1 = c(234,24,34,68), var2 = c(1456,456,456,343), rank = NA)

    df <- df[order(df$var2, df$var1, decreasing = TRUE),]
    df$rank <- seq(1:nrow(df))
```

I would prefer dww's method since you can directly specify the sorting order for every variable. You cannot do that with order() as far as I am concerned

Comment: in case if var2 has same values for two rows, I have to consider var1 to give rank for those tow rows

Comment: That's what the ordering by the second variable does.

Answer (score 0):

This is a base way similar to @ReelSaemon's answer but I make the data keep its original order.

```
ind <- order(df$var2, df$var1, decreasing = T)
df$rank <- seq(nrow(df))[order(ind)]
df

#   var1 var2 rank
# 1  234 1456    1
# 2   24  456    3
# 3   34  456    2
# 4   68  343    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in `base R`, we can use `rank` with `ties.method`

```
with(df, rank(-var2, -var1, ties.method = 'last'))
```

Comment: I don't think base `rank` accepts multiple vectors. (unlike e.g. `order`, which does).